# How to upload an image to a website using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to upload the image to Quora using selenium python but unlike most of the upload button options I couldn't find working 'XPATH' or 'ID' from the website. While try with Xpath and ID I'm getting this error

> "TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable".

Here is the code I used:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
               EC.presence_of_element_located(
                         (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="front"]'))).send_keys(image_path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To uploade file automatically you will have to send it to a special web element. Normally it has `input` tag name and type attribute equals to file.
So, instead of

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(                         (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="front"]'))).send_keys(image_path)
```

Try this:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(                         (By.XPATH, '//input[@type="file"]'))).send_keys(image_path)
```